# Exact terminology of types in Scheme

Tags: types, lisp, scheme

I am looking for a standard doc about types of Scheme. For instance, As types don't need to be explicitly specified in a program, I do not know it is `bool` or `boolean`; `LIST` or `LISTE`; `int` or `Nat`; `List[]` or `List[alpha]`...

Another small question is how "atomic expression" is defined. For instance, is `'(1 2 3)` an atomic expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mit-scheme/stable.pkg/7.7.1/scheme.pdf) is the standards manual for MIT scheme.  Depending on which scheme you're using, this might or might not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

As you point out, types don't need to be explicitly specified. The notion of types is therefore largely missing from the language specification.

There are some languages--Typed Racket comes to mind--that build a typed language on top of (what used to be) Scheme, and these languages define their own types.

There are also contract systems that give names to classes of values. Again, I can point to Racket as an example of this, but I'm confident that there are similar systems out there.

Without being more specific, then, there's no general answer to your question.

The term "atomic" is generally used to refer to values that are not "compound data"; that is, values that don't contain other values. A list is definitely not atomic, and a symbol is.